# HSQLDB error while creating a VIEW

Tags: integration-testing, hsqldb, in-memory-database

I am using HSQLDB for my integration tests to create tables and views in-memory. When I run my test, it fails to create the view. I get the below mentioned exception

```
Error thrown executing CREATE VIEW `ipv6space_view` AS SELECT 
`ipv6space`.`id` AS `id`, `ipv6space`.`ipvpn_id` AS `ipvpn_id`, 
INET6_NTOA(`ipv6space`.`base_address`) AS `base_address`, 
`ipv6space`.`length` AS `length`, `ipv6space`.`type` AS `type`, 
`ipv6space`.`purpose` AS `purpose`, `ipv6space`.`ptr` AS `ptr`, 
`ipv6space`.`abonnement_id` AS `abonnement_id` FROM `ipv6space` : 
unexpected token:  required: AS
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token:  required: AS
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
```

The same statement works fine when I try it with MYSQL.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn on MySQL compatibility mode with this statement:

```
 set database sql syntax mys true
```